# How to dump goroutine stacktraces?

Tags: go

I have Java background, and I love to use signal QUIT to inspect Java thread dump.

How to let Golang print out all goroutines stack trace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the stacktrace of a panic (and store as a variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103182/how-to-get-the-stacktrace-of-a-panic-and-store-as-a-variable)

Comment: You can `kill -ABRT <pid>` to any Go process to kill and get a goroutine stack trace dump.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

To print the stack trace for the *current* goroutine, use [`PrintStack()` from `runtime/debug`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack).

> > PrintStack prints to standard error the stack trace returned by Stack.

For example:

```
import(
   "runtime/debug"
)
...    
debug.PrintStack()
```

To print the stack trace for *all* goroutines use [`Lookup`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/#Lookup) and [`WriteTo`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/#Profile.WriteTo) from [`runtime/pprof`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/).

```
func Lookup(name string) *Profile
// Lookup returns the profile with the given name,
// or nil if no such profile exists.

func (p *Profile) WriteTo(w io.Writer, debug int) error
// WriteTo writes a pprof-formatted snapshot of the profile to w.
// If a write to w returns an error, WriteTo returns that error.
// Otherwise, WriteTo returns nil.
```

> Each Profile has a unique name. A few profiles are predefined:
>
> goroutine    - stack traces of all current goroutines
>   heap         - a sampling of all heap allocations
>   threadcreate - stack traces that led to the creation of new OS threads
>   block        - stack traces that led to blocking on synchronization primitives

For example:

```
pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(os.Stdout, 1)
```

Comment: Does it print stack trace of all goroutines?

Comment: It should, it calls `Stack`.

"Stack returns a formatted stack trace of the goroutine that calls it. For each routine, it includes the source line information and PC value, then attempts to discover, for Go functions, the calling function or method and the text of the line containing the invocation."

Comment: Sorry, it prints the current goroutine stack trace only.

Comment: @HowardGuo I've added an example using runtime/pprof to dump all stack traces.

Comment: thank you very much. may I suggest using `WriteTo(os.Stdout, 1)` instead of 0? so that stack trace information will contain actual symbol instead of memory address.

Comment: I think this only outputs each thread's currently running goroutine, not *all* goroutines, ex: http://play.golang.org/p/0hVB0_LMdm

Comment: @rogerdpack it says "goroutine - stack traces of all current goroutines". operative word being "current".

Comment: Using `2` instead of `1` for the second argument (`debug`) of `WriteTo()` will give you the same style trace as you get with `SIGQUIT`/`panic`, which I find more useful.

Answer (score 53):

There is an HTTP frontend for the `runtime/pprof` package mentioned in Intermernet's answer.  Import the [net/http/pprof](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) package to register an HTTP handler for `/debug/pprof`:

```
import _ "net/http/pprof"
import _ "net/http"
```

Start an HTTP listener if you do not have one already:

```
go func() {
    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil))
}()
```

Then point a browser to `http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof` for a menu, or `http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=2` for a full goroutine stack dump.

There are other fun things you can learn about your running code this way too.  Check out the blog post for examples and more details: 
http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: i made it run by it only shows the goroutines executed as far I see. Is there any way I could see all the "methods" that are executed after the main.go launches?

Answer (score 48):

Similar to Java, SIGQUIT can be used to print a stack trace of a Go program and its goroutines.
A key difference, however, is that by default sending SIGQUIT to Java programs do not terminate them, while Go programs do exit.

This approach requires no code change to print a stack trace of all goroutines of existing programs.

The environment variable GOTRACEBACK ([see documentation of the runtime package](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/)) controls the amount of output generated. For example, to include all goroutines, set GOTRACEBACK=all.

The printing of the stack trace is triggered by an unexpected runtime condition (unhandled signal), originally documented in [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5146a93e72e870b06150c5419e1b83056ecc697b), making it available since at least Go 1.1.

---

Alternatively, if modifying source code is an option, see other answers.

---

Note that in a Linux terminal, SIGQUIT can be conveniently sent with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

Comment: While looking through docs I didn't find any mentions of SIGQUIT, rather SIGABRT. From my own tests (with go 1.7) the latter also worked over the former.

Comment: this should be the top answer.

Comment: The docs refer to "when a Go
program fails due to an unrecovered panic or an unexpected runtime condition". An uncaught signal (SIGQUIT, etc) is one of the latter. Why did I mention SIGQUIT? Because the OP expresses their love for using SIGQUIT with Java, and this answer emphasizes the similarity. Rewording the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 45):

To mimic the Java behaviour of stack-dump on SIGQUIT but still leaving the program running:

```golang
go func() {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    buf := make([]byte, 1<<20)
    for {
        <-sigs
        stacklen := runtime.Stack(buf, true)
        log.Printf("=== received SIGQUIT ===\n*** goroutine dump...\n%s\n*** end\n", buf[:stacklen])
    }
}()
```

Comment: I think this is what the author was really looking for- mimics what Java does when you send a kill -QUIT. One small change I had to make was to change the first line of the for() loop to: "<- sigs". In other words, just discard the signal after waiting on it. Recent versions of Go will not let you declare a variable without later using it.

Comment: @Bryan, are you willing to license this under BSD or other more-permissive terms additional to the CC-BY-SA 3.0 required by StackOverflow?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you can find much the same thing here under Apache licence: https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/blob/404c7a1ad4ae6dde1ed1d2cb55f5832ecc72f222/weaver/main.go#L163

Comment: I slightly improved this to print debug if it receives an os.Interupt signal, if a second signal comes in quickly (< 1 second) it exits, https://play.golang.org/p/dWgWrDFBOth

Answer (score 31):

You can use [runtime.Stack](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack) to get the stack trace of all goroutines:

```
buf := make([]byte, 1<<16)
runtime.Stack(buf, true)
fmt.Printf("%s", buf)
```

From the documentation:

```
func Stack(buf []byte, all bool) int
```

> Stack formats a stack trace of the calling goroutine into buf and
>   returns the number of bytes written to buf. If all is true, Stack
>   formats stack traces of all other goroutines into buf after the trace
>   for the current goroutine.

Comment: This includes backtraces from *all* goroutines, nice!

Comment: Is this the format that an unrecovered panic boils down to use?

Comment: Don't forget to add string(buf) or you'll print the raw bytes there.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or perhaps the functionality has changed, but this doesn't retrieve anything for me except an empty slice of bytes?

Comment: @koda there is no need to do `string(buf)` here, `fmt.Printf("%s", buf)` and `fmt.Printf("%s", string(buf))` do the exact same thing (see docs for `fmt` package); the only difference here is that the `string` version will copy the bytes from `buf` needlessly

Comment: note that `runtime.Stack` returns the number of bytes it actually wrote inside `buf` and so you should manually slice `buf` to that length when printing it, to avoid writing a bunch of 0 bytes (which may be ignored by terminals but will show up in a file that output is redirected to)

Comment: Note that the zero-initialization is necessary here. Trying to create a buffer with `make([]byte, 0, bufsize)` doesn't write any bytes, as the runtime does a length check instead of a capacity check. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f4722d84499cc07fe8c8beb9b3154e59b7d21adf/src/runtime/mprof.go#L853

Answer (score 31):

Press **CTRL+\**

(If you run it in a terminal and just want to kill your program and dump the go routines etc)

I found this question looking for the key sequence. Just wanted a quick and easy way to tell if my program is leaking go routines :)

Comment: This is why I love Go so much. It has all these features that make it way better than C or C++.

Comment: @user1766438 Ctrl+\ is the default terminal key sequence for SIGQUIT and has nothing to do with golang

Comment: @phuclv yes but a C++ -compiled program doesn't print the stack trace when receiving SIGQUIT

Answer (score 14):

On *NIX systems (including OSX) send a signal abort `SIGABRT`:

`pkill -SIGABRT program_name`

Comment: Apparently, sending SIGQUIT to a Java process [does not terminate it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1367/6jalj6mv1/index.html) like SIGABRT will.

Comment: I found this to be the simplest and most matching solution to the original question. Often you need a stacktrace right away, without changing your code.

Answer (score 10):

**By default, press `^\` keys ( *CTRL+\* ) to dump the stack traces of all goroutines.**

---

**Otherwise, for more granular control, you can use `panic`. The simple way as of [Go 1.6+](https://blog.golang.org/go1.6):**

```
go func() {
    s := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(s, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    <-s
    panic("give me the stack")
}()
```

**Then, run your program like so:**

```
# Press ^\ to dump the stack traces of all the user-created goroutines
$ GOTRACEBACK=all go run main.go
```

---

**If you also want to print go runtime goroutines:**

```
$ GOTRACEBACK=system go run main.go
```

---

**Here are all the GOTRACEBACK options:**

- `GOTRACEBACK=none` omits the goroutine stack traces entirely.
- `GOTRACEBACK=single` **(the default)** behaves as described above.
- `GOTRACEBACK=all` adds stack traces for all user-created goroutines.
- `GOTRACEBACK=system` is like `all` but adds stack frames for run-time functions and shows goroutines created internally by the run-time.
- `GOTRACEBACK=crash` is like `system` but crashes in an operating system-specific manner instead of exiting. For example, on Unix systems, the crash raises `SIGABRT` to trigger a core dump.

---

**[Here is the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#hdr-Environment_Variables)**

> The GOTRACEBACK variable controls the amount of output generated when a Go program fails due to an unrecovered panic or an unexpected runtime condition.
>
> By default, a failure prints a stack trace for the current goroutine, eliding functions internal to the run-time system, and then exits with exit code 2. The failure prints stack traces for all goroutines if there is no current goroutine or the failure is internal to the run-time.
>
> For historical reasons, the GOTRACEBACK settings 0, 1, and 2 are synonyms for none, all, and system, respectively.
>
> The runtime/debug package's SetTraceback function allows increasing the amount of output at run time, but it cannot reduce the amount below that specified by the environment variable. See https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetTraceback.

Answer (score 5):

It's necessary to use the length returned by `runtime.Stack()` to avoid printing a bunch of empty lines after your stack trace.  The following recovery function prints a nicely formatted trace:

```
if r := recover(); r != nil {
    log.Printf("Internal error: %v", r))
    buf := make([]byte, 1<<16)
    stackSize := runtime.Stack(buf, true)
    log.Printf("%s\n", string(buf[0:stackSize]))
}
```

Comment: There is no `runtime.Trace`; `runtime.Stack` [was already mentioned a year and a half ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19712747/55504).

Comment: I've never seen that; what platform are you running on?

Comment: What is it you haven't seen?  The code should run on all platforms; I've tested it on Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04, and Mac.

Comment: Never seen empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
kill -3 YOUR_PROCESS_PID_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Package [errors](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#WithStack) allows you to dump the error with stack trace. For example with the function `WithStack`

> WithStack annotates err with a stack trace at the point WithStack was called

```
package main

import (
"fmt"

"github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func main() {
    cause := errors.New("whoops")
    err := errors.WithStack(cause)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", err)
}
```

Comment: `fmt.Println` does not print the stacktrace, you need to use for example `fmt.Printf("%+v", err)` instead, to have the stacktrace printed.