# How to debug a deadlocked process written in golang

Tags: go

I have a process written in golang that runs as a daemon.

After a few days it stops producing output with no apparent reason.  I think it might be an internal deadlock.  If I do a `strace -p <PID>` I can see the line

```
futex(0x9aaba0, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
```

and apparently that call never ends.  I would like to use the already running process (since I don't know how/when to trigger the bug again) to debug the problem.

How can I see what goroutines are running and where they?  How can I dump from the process whatever other information might be useful to debug the problem?

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354810/how-can-i-dump-all-a-go-processs-stacks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces

Comment: I think, without recompiling with some debug output, this will be pretty difficult. From https://golang.org/doc/gdb#Inspecting_the_stack : "GDB does not understand Go programs well." ... "As a consequence, although GDB can be useful in some situations, it is not a reliable debugger for Go programs, particularly heavily concurrent ones. Moreover, it is not a priority for the Go project to address these issues, which are difficult. In short, the instructions below should be taken only as a guide to how to use GDB when it works, not as a guarantee of success."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces may be useful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can send any go program a `QUIT` signal, and it will exit with a full stack trace, showing the state of all goroutines, and how they are blocked.

As for `strace`, go programs are always multithreaded, so you always need to add the `-f` option

Comment: Unfortunately, the daemon captures the QUIT signal to do some cleanup and then calling `exit(0)`.  Good point with the `-f` option.  I am afraid that I will need to recompile the daemon with some added debugging capabilities, and then hope for the bug to happen again :-(

Answer (score 2):

Here are some methods from [Deadlocks: the dark side of concurrency](https://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/deadlocks-in-go/) (covers what a deadlock is, how to debug, and and how to avoid them)

- Use SIGQUIT

  - This produces a nice backtrace on Unix based system
  - Send it with `kill -QUIT pid`
  - Or press `CTRL-\`
  - Does not work on Windows
- Use the http debug handler

  - Retrieve the backtrace with a web browser or curl
  - Work on all platforms