# Program hangs for a while occasionally

Tags: linux, go

I have written a simple KV database in golang, this database runs smoothly most time, however, it hangs for a few seconds occasionally.

The version of golang and linux is:

1. go version: 1.12.5
2. linux version: CentOS release 6.7 (Final) 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64

Cpu,Mem,IO info:[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq6Bc.png), [MEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfMiB.png), [IO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Yjr.png)

I've tried some ways to debug this problem:

1. Import http/pprof package and gops package, however, I fail to get process heap stack because the process is totally unresponsive when it hangs.
2. Strace tool is used to get process syscalls:

```xml
process 32573 attached with 178 threads
[pid 172460] 11:12:25.260132 futex(0xc1dc4d0f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 24633] 11:12:25.260197 futex(0xc0dc3012c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 34073] 11:12:25.260209 futex(0xc33b8464c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 34071] 11:12:25.260233 futex(0xc3b259c148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 34069] 11:12:25.260264 futex(0xc1f7eef648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33989] 11:12:25.260275 futex(0xc368336f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33988] 11:12:25.260285 futex(0xc36795cbc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33987] 11:12:25.260293 futex(0xc368336bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33986] 11:12:25.260313 futex(0xc36795c848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33984] 11:12:25.260320 futex(0xc36795c4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33983] 11:12:25.260342 futex(0xc3683364c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33982] 11:12:25.260350 futex(0xc36795c148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33980] 11:12:25.260360 futex(0xc0b79d1d48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33978] 11:12:25.260368 futex(0xc0b79d19c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33977] 11:12:25.260376 futex(0xc3720559c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33974] 11:12:25.260385 futex(0xc0b79d1648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33973] 11:12:25.260393 futex(0xc3720552c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 33972] 11:12:25.260402 futex(0xc4959e4bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32787] 11:12:25.260411 futex(0xc000a44f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32786] 11:12:25.260421 futex(0xc0d5df4848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32785] 11:12:25.260431 futex(0xc0d5e5e4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32784] 11:12:25.260440 futex(0xc0d60184c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32782] 11:12:25.260448 futex(0xc0a0eea4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32781] 11:12:25.260456 futex(0xc0d5c2c848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32779] 11:12:25.260465 futex(0xc00068ebc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32777] 11:12:25.260473 futex(0xc0d5df44c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32776] 11:12:25.260482 futex(0xc0005d3648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32775] 11:12:25.260491 futex(0xc000a059c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32774] 11:12:25.260500 futex(0xc000a772c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32773] 11:12:25.260508 futex(0xc0d5ed64c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32772] 11:12:25.260518 futex(0xc0d5df24c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32770] 11:12:25.260526 futex(0xc0d5d524c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32767] 11:12:25.260534 futex(0xc0a6c66148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32766] 11:12:25.260542 futex(0xc0d5d4e4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32763] 11:12:25.260552 futex(0x1cdada0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32761] 11:12:25.260561 futex(0xc000b54848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32760] 11:12:25.260569 futex(0xc000b60848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32756] 11:12:25.260578 futex(0xc0005d32c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32755] 11:12:25.260586 futex(0xc000a05648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32754] 11:12:25.260594 futex(0xc0d5ed6148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32753] 11:12:25.260603 futex(0xc000185648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32752] 11:12:25.260611 futex(0xc000a76f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32751] 11:12:25.260620 futex(0xc08a27c148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32750] 11:12:25.260629 futex(0xc0d5e5e148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32748] 11:12:25.260643 futex(0xc075230148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32747] 11:12:25.260652 futex(0xc0d5df4148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32746] 11:12:25.260659 futex(0xc075038148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32745] 11:12:25.260667 futex(0xc0d5df2148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32744] 11:12:25.260675 futex(0xc0004a12c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32743] 11:12:25.260683 futex(0xc073c7e148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32742] 11:12:25.260692 futex(0xc0d5d52148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32741] 11:12:25.260702 futex(0xc0d5d50148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32740] 11:12:25.260711 futex(0xc0d5d4e148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32739] 11:12:25.260718 futex(0xc0d5c2c148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32738] 11:12:25.260726 futex(0xc0d5c2a148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32737] 11:12:25.260734 futex(0xc000a44848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32736] 11:12:25.260742 futex(0xc000b564c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32735] 11:12:25.260750 futex(0xc000b544c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32734] 11:12:25.260758 futex(0xc000b604c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32733] 11:12:25.260766 futex(0xc000b1c4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32732] 11:12:25.260775 futex(0xc0001a4f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32728] 11:12:25.260784 futex(0xc0001852c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32727] 11:12:25.260794 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...> <unfinished ...>
[pid 32725] 11:12:25.260806 futex(0xc00068e4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32724] 11:12:25.260815 futex(0xc000aa9648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32723] 11:12:25.260823 futex(0xc000aa92c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32722] 11:12:25.260833 futex(0xc00083abc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32721] 11:12:25.260842 futex(0xc000868848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32718] 11:12:25.260851 futex(0xc000a76bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32651] 11:12:25.260859 futex(0xc000aa8bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32650] 11:12:25.260867 futex(0xc000aa8848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32649] 11:12:25.260875 futex(0xc0008eb648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32648] 11:12:25.260883 futex(0xc00097dd48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32647] 11:12:25.260891 futex(0xc00097d9c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32646] 11:12:25.260899 futex(0xc00097d648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32644] 11:12:25.260908 futex(0xc0009e1d48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32643] 11:12:25.260918 futex(0xc0008eaf48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32642] 11:12:25.260926 futex(0xc0008eabc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32639] 11:12:25.260935 futex(0xc00097d2c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32638] 11:12:25.260945 futex(0xc00097cf48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32637] 11:12:25.260954 futex(0xc0009e1648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32635] 11:12:25.260963 futex(0xc0008ea4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32634] 11:12:25.260971 futex(0xc00097c848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32633] 11:12:25.260979 futex(0xc0009a6848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32631] 11:12:25.260986 futex(0xc0009e12c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32630] 11:12:25.260994 futex(0xc000aa84c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32629] 11:12:25.261002 futex(0xc000a76848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32628] 11:12:25.261009 futex(0xc000a04bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32627] 11:12:25.261024 futex(0xc000b60148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32626] 11:12:25.261032 futex(0xc000a04848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32625] 11:12:25.261040 futex(0xc000b54148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32624] 11:12:25.261047 futex(0xc000b56148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32623] 11:12:25.261067 futex(0xc0009e0f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32621] 11:12:25.261076 futex(0xc0009e0bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32620] 11:12:25.261083 futex(0xc0009e0848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32619] 11:12:25.261101 futex(0xc00083a848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32618] 11:12:25.261110 futex(0xc0000f59c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32617] 11:12:25.261118 futex(0xc000a044c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32616] 11:12:25.261127 futex(0xc00097c4c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32613] 11:12:25.261136 futex(0xc0005d2bc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32612] 11:12:25.261144 futex(0xc000184f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32611] 11:12:25.261152 futex(0xc0009e04c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32610] 11:12:25.261160 futex(0xc000a444c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32609] 11:12:25.261169 futex(0xc000a764c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32608] 11:12:25.261178 futex(0xc000aa8148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32606] 11:12:25.261186 futex(0xc000a44148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32604] 11:12:25.261194 futex(0xc0009e0148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32603] 11:12:25.261207 futex(0xc0009a6148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32602] 11:12:25.261216 futex(0xc00097c148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32601] 11:12:25.261224 futex(0xc0008ea148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32600] 11:12:25.261232 futex(0xc000868148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32598] 11:12:25.261240 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...> <unfinished ...>
[pid 32596] 11:12:25.261249 futex(0xc0000c3648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32595] 11:12:25.261257 futex(0xc0004a0848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32594] 11:12:25.261266 futex(0xc000184848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32593] 11:12:25.261276 futex(0xc0005d2848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32592] 11:12:25.261285 futex(0xc0000f5648, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32590] 11:12:25.261294 futex(0xc0001a4848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32588] 11:12:25.261302 futex(0xc0005d2148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32587] 11:12:25.261310 futex(0xc0000f4f48, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32586] 11:12:25.261318 futex(0xc0001a44c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32585] 11:12:25.261325 futex(0xc000184148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32584] 11:12:25.261334 futex(0xc0004a04c8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32579] 11:12:25.261343 futex(0xc0001a4148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32578] 11:12:25.261350 futex(0x1cdacb8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32577] 11:12:25.261359 futex(0xc0000f4148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32575] 11:12:25.261368 futex(0xc0000c2848, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32574] 11:12:25.261377 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...> <unfinished ...>
[pid 32573] 11:12:25.261385 futex(0x1cbe8e8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32574] 11:12:25.264099 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = 0 <0.002704>
[pid 32574] 11:12:25.264131 epoll_pwait(4<[eventpoll]>, {}, 128, 0, NULL) = 0 <0.000014>
```

```xml
[pid 32574] 11:12:25.264197 nanosleep({0, 10000000},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 34072] 11:12:31.236049 read(16699<socket:[371657496]>,  <unfinished ...>
```

```xml
[pid 34070] 11:12:31.236128 read(16691<socket:[371657488]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 33985] 11:12:31.236142 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
[pid 33981] 11:12:31.236161 futex(0xc06ed9c148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 33979] 11:12:31.236171 futex(0xc0d5df44c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 33976] 11:12:31.236178 futex(0xc3720552c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 33971] 11:12:31.236193 read(7443<socket:[371660645]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 33975] 11:12:31.236243 futex(0xc0004a12c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32789] 11:12:31.236253 futex(0xc06ed9c148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 32788] 11:12:31.236262 futex(0xc000a76bc8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32783] 11:12:31.236270 read(5583<socket:[371824829]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32780] 11:12:31.236295 read(1258<socket:[371660662]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32778] 11:12:31.236311 read(2795<socket:[371660629]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32771] 11:12:31.236339 read(16828<socket:[371657506]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32769] 11:12:31.236356 read(1163<socket:[371770203]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32768] 11:12:31.236370 read(16955<socket:[371657515]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32765] 11:12:31.236385 read(16696<socket:[371657494]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32764] 11:12:31.236398 futex(0xc1f7eef648, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32762] 11:12:31.236423 read(9849<socket:[371825259]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32759] 11:12:31.236437 read(16944<socket:[371657509]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32758] 11:12:31.236451 read(16684<socket:[371657485]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32757] 11:12:31.236473 read(3335<socket:[371657499]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32749] 11:12:31.236493 read(16950<socket:[371657513]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32731] 11:12:31.236509 futex(0xc000868148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32730] 11:12:31.236518 futex(0xc0008ea4c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32729] 11:12:31.236526 futex(0xc0000f5648, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32726] 11:12:31.236535 futex(0xc0d5e5e4c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32720] 11:12:31.236544 read(6925<socket:[371811451]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32719] 11:12:31.236562 read(16702<socket:[371657497]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32717] 11:12:31.236576 read(16713<socket:[371657498]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32645] 11:12:31.236590 read(6490<socket:[371824831]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32640] 11:12:31.236608 futex(0xc0d5d4e148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 32636] 11:12:31.236619 accept4(4105,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32632] 11:12:31.236628 read(9867<socket:[371825263]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32615] 11:12:31.236648 read(2699<socket:[371813455]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 32614] 11:12:31.236665 futex(0xc00068e4c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
```

GC info(from 11:00 to 11:42):

```xml
gc 4547 @519870.695s 0%: 0.64+7727+0.098 ms clock, 30+54557/86497/4449+4.7 ms cpu, 30446->36079->19800 MB, 33340 MB goal, 48 P
GC forced
gc 4548 @519998.441s 0%: 1.4+2698+0.028 ms clock, 70+71/32202/90622+1.3 ms cpu, 30366->30623->14272 MB, 39601 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3465: 921 MB released
scvg3465: inuse: 26152, idle: 73618, sys: 99771, released: 52270, consumed: 47501 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4549 @520121.156s 0%: 0.89+2614+0.029 ms clock, 42+244/31128/89017+1.3 ms cpu, 23255->23387->14064 MB, 28545 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3466: 35 MB released
scvg3466: inuse: 26928, idle: 72843, sys: 99771, released: 51276, consumed: 48494 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4550 @520243.784s 0%: 0.76+2723+0.036 ms clock, 36+184/32007/89703+1.7 ms cpu, 20919->21049->14074 MB, 28129 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3467: 17831 MB released
scvg3467: inuse: 27049, idle: 72722, sys: 99771, released: 69057, consumed: 30714 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4551 @520366.531s 0%: 0.78+2736+0.032 ms clock, 37+174/32370/91383+1.5 ms cpu, 20387->20478->14120 MB, 28149 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3468: 1808 MB released
scvg3468: inuse: 28066, idle: 71704, sys: 99771, released: 70795, consumed: 28976 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4552 @520489.286s 0%: 0.72+2641+0.034 ms clock, 34+258/31377/88676+1.6 ms cpu, 21277->21360->14002 MB, 28240 MB goal, 48 P
GC forced
gc 4553 @520611.942s 0%: 0.41+2648+0.029 ms clock, 20+58/31402/89121+1.4 ms cpu, 21806->21897->14362 MB, 28005 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3469: 34 MB released
scvg3469: inuse: 26701, idle: 73069, sys: 99771, released: 69940, consumed: 29830 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4554 @520734.608s 0%: 0.55+2685+0.038 ms clock, 26+147/32051/88317+1.8 ms cpu, 21565->21877->14352 MB, 28725 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3470: 39 MB released
scvg3470: inuse: 26641, idle: 73130, sys: 99771, released: 69576, consumed: 30195 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4555 @520857.307s 0%: 0.43+2614+0.031 ms clock, 20+0.31/31264/91012+1.5 ms cpu, 20760->20849->14183 MB, 28704 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3471: 394 MB released
scvg3471: inuse: 27167, idle: 72604, sys: 99771, released: 69929, consumed: 29841 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4556 @520979.937s 0%: 0.51+2716+0.026 ms clock, 24+116/32239/91899+1.2 ms cpu, 22069->22175->14134 MB, 28366 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3472: 720 MB released
scvg3472: inuse: 27667, idle: 72104, sys: 99771, released: 69954, consumed: 29817 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4557 @521102.679s 0%: 0.45+2737+0.051 ms clock, 21+38/32726/89390+2.4 ms cpu, 21606->21995->14750 MB, 28269 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3473: 25 MB released
scvg3473: inuse: 32397, idle: 67369, sys: 99766, released: 66966, consumed: 32800 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4558 @521225.432s 0%: 6.2+2703+0.037 ms clock, 300+104/32314/90152+1.7 ms cpu, 27118->27332->14253 MB, 29500 MB goal, 48 P
GC forced
gc 4559 @521348.157s 0%: 10+2655+0.028 ms clock, 521+447/31809/89384+1.3 ms cpu, 23382->23651->14316 MB, 28507 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3474: 51 MB released
scvg3474: inuse: 26034, idle: 73736, sys: 99771, released: 66841, consumed: 32930 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4560 @521470.837s 0%: 9.8+2605+0.026 ms clock, 474+143/30936/90046+1.2 ms cpu, 22733->22833->14100 MB, 28632 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3475: 79 MB released
scvg3475: inuse: 26480, idle: 73290, sys: 99771, released: 66906, consumed: 32864 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4561 @521593.476s 0%: 0.41+2615+0.046 ms clock, 19+159/30798/88548+2.2 ms cpu, 20629->20769->14033 MB, 28201 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3476: 2438 MB released
scvg3476: inuse: 27789, idle: 71982, sys: 99771, released: 69305, consumed: 30465 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4562 @521716.106s 0%: 0.51+2673+0.051 ms clock, 24+88/32054/92490+2.4 ms cpu, 21751->21896->14198 MB, 28066 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3477: 1294 MB released
scvg3477: inuse: 29695, idle: 70076, sys: 99771, released: 69666, consumed: 30104 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4563 @521838.810s 0%: 0.47+2635+0.028 ms clock, 22+111/31434/90845+1.3 ms cpu, 22623->22705->14057 MB, 28397 MB goal, 48 P
GC forced
gc 4564 @521961.461s 0%: 0.46+2727+0.031 ms clock, 22+155/32528/93412+1.5 ms cpu, 19763->19851->14138 MB, 28114 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3478: 142 MB released
scvg3478: inuse: 25743, idle: 74027, sys: 99771, released: 69729, consumed: 30042 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4565 @522084.205s 0%: 0.44+2657+0.029 ms clock, 21+214/31701/90716+1.4 ms cpu, 20424->20514->14179 MB, 28276 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3479: 28 MB released
scvg3479: inuse: 28391, idle: 71380, sys: 99771, released: 69228, consumed: 30543 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4566 @522206.879s 0%: 0.38+2652+0.033 ms clock, 18+108/31342/90698+1.6 ms cpu, 23690->23781->14146 MB, 28359 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3480: 557 MB released
scvg3480: inuse: 27188, idle: 72582, sys: 99771, released: 68737, consumed: 31034 (MB)
GC forced
gc 4567 @522329.545s 0%: 0.55+2585+0.031 ms clock, 26+47/30887/89360+1.5 ms cpu, 22082->22182->14378 MB, 28292 MB goal, 48 P
scvg3481: 27 MB released
scvg3481: inuse: 28056, idle: 71715, sys: 99771, released: 67790, consumed: 31981 (MB)
```

Vmstat info:

```xml
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0 2538448 965376 985720 193366176    0    0  7468  4144 30760 37141  3  0 97  0  0
 0  0 2538448 866052 985720 193425296    0    0  6096  4796 29720 36705  4  0 95  0  0  
 3  2 2538448 781104 985720 193466992    0    0  8868  4888 31129 40341  3  0 97  0  0  
 0  0 2538448 684132 985720 193525088    0    0  6456  7256 27751 34601  4  0 95  0  0  
 1  0 2538448 591752 985728 193568112    0    0  7588  7448 31251 39921  2  1 97  0  0  
 0  1 2538596 603712 985724 193519232    0  148  9192  5040 85975 41792  3  1 96  0  0  
 6  1 2538824 581488 985724 193478368    0  228 12044  8736 76500 44506  3  1 96  0  0  
 1  0 2539052 588596 985720 193401248    0  228 17488  7708 95530 47809  5  1 94  1  0  
 0  0 2539228 605584 985584 193341440    0  176  7720  3880 85563 38079  3  1 97  0  0  
 3  0 2539344 598864 985280 193296800    0  116  9784  4296 48443 41580  3  1 96  0  0  
 3  0 2540228 4245764 959772 189644656    0  884  7732  4464 594631 41907  3  3 94  0  0      
 0  0 2540588 5716636 958540 188141504    0  360 12832 35124 240269 37573  3  1 96  0  0      
 2  0 2540588 5614180 958540 188207216    0    0 13784  2984 27044 34481  2  0 97  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 5433884 958560 188269600    0    0  9644 538844 51809 47156  3  1 94  2  0      
 3  0 2540588 5333084 958584 188335344    0    0 15500 552292 53730 74434  2  1 93  4  0      
 4  0 2540588 5201944 958588 188409344    0    0 20760  5628 31898 40993  3  1 96  0  0  
 3  0 2540588 5110636 958588 188476512    0    0 17764  8540 29821 38110  3  1 97  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 4966540 958596 188550064    0    0 18972  4364 29049 35744  3  1 96  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 4816128 958604 188614416    0    0 14372  3448 29185 36645  3  1 97  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 4655996 958612 188687328    0    0 20540 16648 29179 36005  3  1 96  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 4476048 958620 188754208    0    0 16456  4308 29029 35896  3  1 96  0  0  
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st 
 1  0 2540588 4333448 958620 188818256    0    0 13888 13564 26797 32078  3  1 97  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 4117432 958620 188887184    0    0 15688  3948 29182 35576  3  1 96  0  0  
 6  0 2540588 3933804 958620 188948192    0    0  9872  1600 26391 31619  3  1 96  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 3753960 958628 189011008    0    0 11588  4104 32898 39632  3  1 96  0  0  
 2  0 2540588 3577940 958632 189074000    0    0 12528  4576 28383 36093  2  1 97  0  0  
50  0 2540588 3457128 958648 189134080    0    0  8516 182148 67199 31207 47  1 51  1  0      
49  0 2540588 3654512 958664 188890368    0    0  8172 42092 77663 13805 91  1  8  0  0  
37 11 2540588 3532092 958664 188962656    0    0 23604  7932 67246 12802 92  1  6  1  0  
 2  0 2540588 3423520 958676 189049424    0    0 41140 36392 49538 38934 30  1 67  3  0  
13  0 2540588 3353936 958676 189119248    0    0 14636  3820 31720 37868  6  1 94  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 3288452 958684 189185456    0    0 14984 10288 27419 29717  5  1 94  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 3228116 958684 189244896    0    0  8464  3180 27235 33955  2  0 97  0  0  
 2  0 2540588 3181408 958684 189290576    0    0 11088  2968 27061 32916  3  0 97  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 3115948 958692 189356912    0    0 13488 22464 30301 38231  2  0 97  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 3049144 958700 189423712    0    0 13900  4504 30000 37108  3  1 96  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 2985992 958708 189486880    0    0 12216 10648 28751 34676  2  0 97  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 2922520 958708 189551104    0    0 13076  3224 28077 34695  3  0 97  0  0  
 0  1 2540588 2863000 958708 189611968    0    0  6900  2748 27320 34072  3  0 97  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 2799620 958720 189674800    0    0 13164 18360 29380 36358  3  1 96  0  0  
 0  0 2540588 2746148 958728 189727936    0    0 12840  4884 29313 37243  2  0 97  0  0  
 1  0 2540588 2686116 958740 189788928    0    0  8024 33552 28742 34802  3  0 97  0  0
```

as the second strace info block shown, when the time was between 11:12:25.264197 and 11:12:31.236049, no syscall was invoked, but the client was still writing data to this database.

I have no ideas about what the process is doing when the process hangs.

**Any suggestions to help me investigate this problem?**

**Is there any tools to get process stack when the process hangs?**

Maybe I need the answer to this question: [How can I dump all a Go process's stacks without killing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354810/how-can-i-dump-all-a-go-processs-stacks-without-killing-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: 1) look at the machine with vmstat/top etc see if the problem is elsewhere 2)stack dump https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398062/1153938 . If you want actual help here on the SO you need to provide code

Comment: @Vorsprung Thanks for your reply. The cpu, io and memory acts as usual on linux server. I think stackoverflow.com/a/27398062/1153938 works the same as using http/pprof package but i will try it.

Comment: Is this writing to disk or is it in memory?

Comment: Tip1: it might allocated too much RAM, and waits for swap. Tip2: Go garbage collector suspends the world.

Comment: @peterh 1. Swap is off on my linux server 2. GC info has been uploaded, it seems usual, sweep time is short.

Comment: @Jesse The database uses LSM structure, it flushes memtable to disk at the time memtable is full

Comment: @Clize Turning the swap off is **very** amateur, a clear signature that you don't understand, how the memory management works. It is very likely, that the lack of swap + the huge RAM need of go apps cause your troubles. Turn the swap on, and check again.

Comment: @peterh Sorry for my late reply. I turn the swap on but the problem still exists. Vmstat shows no swap in and out when the process hangs.