# Is there a tool to detect when I forget to close goroutines?

Tags: go

When I do this

```
done := make(chan bool)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    go func() {
        done <- true
    }()
}
<-done
```

instead of this

```
done := make(chan bool)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    go func() {
        done <- true
    }()
}
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    <-done
}
```

Am I leaking goroutines if I do not close them and Is there a tool to detect when I forget to close goroutines?

Comment: `leak` always bindings to business(what your code want to do). If your program running well, leaving the routines, that's not `leak`. my opinion

Comment: @JiangYD You are right I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: [`runtime.GoroutineProfile`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GoroutineProfile) has all the goroutines running and their stacktraces. Maybe better, [this answer describes using `runtime/pprof`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces) to get the whole traces printed. It's up to you then to figure out if the number of routines running is expected or not, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are leaking 9 goroutines in you first example.

I don't believe there's any tool to tell you this.

would be an interesting thing to make, if there's a way to query for all existing non-system (ie: gc) goroutines.

Probably can do something with: [runtime.Stack](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack), but it would be super-specific 
to a given codebase as you likely have some "good" goroutines and some "rogue" ones.

Update: Feb 4, 2016

I got curious on this, so I made a really simple (and terribly named) library to do a diff of goroutines over time.  A simplistic leak detector.   https://github.com/dbudworth/greak