# How to prevent Go program from crashing after accidental panic?

Tags: go

Think of a large project which deals with tons of concurrent requests handled by its own goroutine. It happens that there is a bug in the code and one of these requests will cause panic due to a nil reference.

In Java, C# and many other languages, this would end up in a exception which would stop the request without any harm to other healthy requests. In go, that would crash the entire program.

AFAIK, I'd have to have `recover()` for every single new go routine creation. Is that the only way to prevent entire program from crashing?

UPDATE: adding `recover()` call for every gorouting creation seems OK. What about third-party libraries? If third party creates goroutines without `recover()` safe net, it seems there is NOTHING to be done.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Note you can use `defer panicRecover()` and call `recover()` from there.

Comment: Note that the stdlib http server already does this for you (though having it be the default is regarded by many to be a mistake)

Comment: It is worth finding the cause of the nil dereference since that is most likely a logic issue.

Comment: Sure, but I'd rather see nil dereference as an error log and fix it ASAP without crashing over and over hurting unrelated requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go the defer-recover-all-the-things, I suggest investing some time to make sure that a clear error message is collected with enough information to promptly act on it.

Writing the panic message to stderr/stdout is not great as it will be very hard to find where the problem is. In my experience the best approach is to invest a bit of time to get your Go programs to handle errors in a reasonable way. `errors.Wrap` from "[github.com/pkg/errors](https://github.com/pkg/errors)" for instance allows you to wrap all errors and get a stack-trace.

Recovering panic is often a necessary evil. Like you say, it's not ideal to crash the entire program just because one requested caused a panic. In most cases recovering panics will not back-fire, but it is possible for a program to end up in a undefined not-recoverable state that only a manual restart can fix. That being said, my suggestion in this case is to make sure your Go program exposes a way to create a core dump.

Here's how to write a core dump to stderr when SIGQUIT is sent to the Go program (eg. `kill pid -QUIT`)

```
go func() {
    // Based on answers to this stackoverflow question:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    for {
        <-sigs

        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "=== received SIGQUIT ===")
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "*** goroutine dump...")

        var buf []byte
        var bufsize int
        var stacklen int

        // Create a stack buffer of 1MB and grow it to at most 100MB if
        // necessary
        for bufsize = 1e6; bufsize < 100e6; bufsize *= 2 {
            buf = make([]byte, bufsize)
            stacklen = runtime.Stack(buf, true)
            if stacklen < bufsize {
                break
            }
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, string(buf[:stacklen]))
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "*** end of dump")
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no way you can handle panic without recover function, a good practice would be using a middleware like function for your safe function, checkout this snippet

https://play.golang.org/p/d_fQWzXnlAm