# How to list all the running goroutines in a go program?

Tags: go

Is there a tool in the official tooling or the third party tool that lets you list all your running goroutines that are running with your main program?

Or something like the observer in Erlang/Elixir?

Comment: List them in what way? They don't have names or IDs. You can get a count of them from [`runtime.NumGoroutine()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumGoroutine).

Comment: The closest you could get to "listing all goroutines" would be dumping all their stack traces, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces but it doesn't seem like that's what you're looking for.

Comment: listing them like `goroutine 1 <some-timestamp-when-it-started-running>` , `goroutine 2 ...`, `goroutine 3 ...` .....

Comment: You'd need to track that yourself; as far as I'm aware Go does not track the timestamp when each goroutine is started, it has no use for that information.

Comment: @Adrian: Strictly speaking, Goroutines _do_ have IDs, but [reading them sends you straight to hell](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecheney/junk/id).

Comment: @Flimzy interesting... I can see why he put that note on it, it's definitely WELL outside of what's supported or covered by the Go1 compatibility promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a stack trace of *all* goroutines:

You can use [`runtime.Stack()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack) with `all` set to `true`:

```golang
func Stack(buf []byte, all bool) int
```

> Stack formats a stack trace of the calling goroutine into buf and returns the number of bytes written to buf. If all is true, Stack formats stack traces of all other goroutines into buf after the trace for the current goroutine.

Comment: If that is the answer OP is looking for, then the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces

Comment: Agreed! I would still keep it as it's the closest to what OP is looking for!

Comment: I think this answer is useful separate from the linked questions. It was just what I was looking for.