# How to detect goroutine leaks?

Tags: go, goroutine

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func cancellation() {
    duration := 150 * time.Millisecond
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), duration)
    defer cancel()

    ch := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(500) * time.Millisecond)
        ch <- "paper"
    }()

    select {
    case d := <-ch:
        fmt.Println("work complete", d)
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("work cancelled")
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("--------------------------------------")
}

func main() {
    cancellation()
}
```

---

Because of unbuffered channel(`ch := make(chan string)`), go-routine leaks due to block on send(`ch <- "paper"`), if main goroutine is not ready to receive.

Using buffered channel `ch := make(chan string, 1)` does not block send(`ch <- "paper"`)

How to detect such go-routine leaks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dump goroutine stacktraces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094099/how-to-dump-goroutine-stacktraces)

Answer (score 2):

There are some packages that let you do that. Two that I've used in the past:

- https://github.com/fortytw2/leaktest
- https://github.com/uber-go/goleak

Generally, they use functionality from the `runtime` package to examine the stack before and after your code runs and report suspected leaks. It's recommended to use them in tests. I found this works well in practice and used it in a couple of projects.

Comment: see also this comment, and all the post in general, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19145992/4466350

Comment: @mh-cbon: I think this is reasonable as a separate question; making the connection between "how to I know if I have goroutine leaks" and "oh I need to look at the stack" is nontrivial. But YMMV.

Comment: For Gomega users, there's now a fully integrated go routine check package https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/onsi/gomega@v1.28.0/gleak; it leverages the Gomega matcher infrastructure. Disclosure: I'm the contributor of the Gomega gleak package and use it in my own as well as some of the Siemens OpenSource github projects, namely Edgeshark.

Comment: First library linked here looks unmaintained.